# Best place to clear out Array before iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

### EDIT: I believe I was going down the wrong path with trying to remove duplicates and needed to clear out the array instead.

Here is example code. I am trying to find the best place to clear out the parent.subdirectories array before each iteration.

```js
const mainArray = [{Id:1,Name:"test",SubDirectoryCount:10,Files:[]}];
const directories = [{Id:56,Name:"Client 2",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:1,Files:[]},{Id:53,Name:"Client 3",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:1,Files:[]},{Id:50,Name:"Client 4",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:1,Files:[]},{Id:48,Name:"Client 5",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:53,Files:[]},{Id:47,Name:"Client 5",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:53,Files:[]},{Id:49,Name:"Client 5",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:53,Files:[]}];

// create flat list
const tmp = mainArray.concat(directories);
tmp.forEach(directory => {
  const parent = tmp.find(item => item.Id === directory.ParentId);

  if(parent) {
      parent.SubDirectories = parent.SubDirectories || [];
      parent.SubDirectories.push(directory)
  }
});

console.log(mainArray)
```

My attempt but, it removes top items before rebuilding JSON.

```
  tmp.forEach((directory) => {
    const parent = tmp.find((item) => item.Id === directory.ParentFk);

    if (parent) {
      parent.SubDirectories = parent.SubDirectories || [];

      const found = parent.SubDirectories.some((el) => el.Id === directory.Id);
      if (!found) {
        parent.SubDirectories.push(directory);
      } else {
        parent.SubDirectories = [];
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: It seems like you have a general misunderstanding. The foreach loop does not rerun when `directory` is updated. You will need to invoke it every time you update the array of object. JS isn’t “reactive” in that sense.

Comment: @Terry, I have this wrapped in a larger function that gets invoked every time a Material UI Treeview Toggle event happens.

Comment: what do you mean by duplicates? just 2 objects with the same ID? and in this case which one is the original to keep?

Comment: @MisterJojo, yes same Id's

Comment: and in this case which one is the original to keep? the first one or the last one ?

Comment: Keep either of them. If they are dupes I just need one of them.

Comment: This need more detail

Comment: @MannyAlvarado added more detail. Basically looking for a best practice on how to not push obj into array if already there with my current code.

Answer (score 1):

simply that ?

```js
const directories = 
  [ { Id: 56, Name: 'Client 2', SubDirectoryCount: 1, ParentId: 1,  Files: [] } 
  , { Id: 53, Name: 'Client 3', SubDirectoryCount: 1, ParentId: 1,  Files: [] } 
  , { Id: 50, Name: 'Client 4', SubDirectoryCount: 1, ParentId: 1,  Files: [] } 
  , { Id: 48, Name: 'Client 5', SubDirectoryCount: 1, ParentId: 53, Files: [] } 
  , { Id: 47, Name: 'Client 5', SubDirectoryCount: 1, ParentId: 53, Files: [] } 
  , { Id: 47, Name: 'Client 5', SubDirectoryCount: 1, ParentId: 53, Files: [] } 
  ] 

for (let index= directories.length; --index;)
  {
  if (index > directories.findIndex(x=>x.Id===directories[index].Id))
    directories.splice(index,1)
  }
console.log( directories )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const directories = [{Id: 56, Name: 'Client 2', SubDirectoryCount: 1, ParentId: 1,  Files: []}, {Id: 53, Name: 'Client 3', SubDirectoryCount: 1, ParentId: 1,  Files: []}, {Id: 50, Name: 'Client 4', SubDirectoryCount: 1, ParentId: 1,  Files: []}, {Id: 48, Name: 'Client 5', SubDirectoryCount: 1, ParentId: 53, Files: []}, {Id: 47, Name: 'Client 5', SubDirectoryCount: 1, ParentId: 53, Files: []}, {Id: 47, Name: 'Client 5', SubDirectoryCount: 1, ParentId: 53, Files: []}]

const result = Object.values(directories.reduce((a, c) => (a[c.Id] = a[c.Id] || c, a), {}))

console.log(result)
```